# MongoDB Stitch GraphQL Custom Mutation Resolver returning null

Tags: mongodb, graphql, apollo-client, mongodb-stitch

GraphQL is a newer feature for MongoDB Stitch, and I know it is in beta, so thank you for your help in advance. I am excited about using GraphQL directly in Stitch so I am hoping that maybe I just overlooked something.

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/graphql/custom-resolvers/) for the return Payload displays the use of bsonType, but when actually entering the JSON Schema for the payload type it asks for you to use "type" instead of "bsonType". It still works using "bsonType" to me which is odd as long as at least one of the properties uses "type".

Below is the function:

```
      const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
      const collection = mongodb.db("<database>").collection("<collection>");
      const query = { _id: BSON.ObjectId(input.id) }
      const update = {
        "$push": {
          "notes": {
            "createdBy": context.user.id, 
            "createdAt": new Date, 
            "text": input.text
          }
        }
      };

      const options = { returnNewDocument: true }

      collection.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).then(updatedDocument => {
        if(updatedDocument) {
      console.log(`Successfully updated document: ${updatedDocument}.`)
    } else {
      console.log("No document matches the provided query.")
    }
    return {
      _id: updatedDocument._id,
      notes: updatedDocument.notes
    }
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to find and update document: ${err}`))
}
```

Here is the Input Type in the customer resolver:

```
  "type": "object",
  "title": "AddNoteToLeadInput",
  "required": [
    "id",
    "text"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "text": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the Payload Type:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "title": "AddNoteToLeadPayload",
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "type": "objectId"
    },
    "notes": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "createdAt": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "createdBy": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When entering the wrong "type" the error states:

> Expected valid values are:[array boolean integer number null object string]

When entering the wrong "bsonType" the error states:

> Expected valid values are:[string object array objectId boolean bool null regex date timestamp int long decimal double number binData]

I've tried every combination I can think of including changing all "bsonType" to "type". I also tried changing the _id to a string when using "type" or objectId when "bsonType". No matter what combination I try when I use the mutation it does what it is supposed to and adds the note into the lead, but the return payload always displays null. I need it to return the _id and note so that it will update the InMemoryCache in Apollo on the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you might be missing a `return` before your call to `collection.findOneAndUpdate()`

I tried this function (similar to yours) and got GraphiQL to return values (with `String` for all the input and payload types)

```
exports = function(input){

  const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
      const collection = mongodb.db("todo").collection("dreams");
      const query = { _id: input.id }
      const update = {
        "$push": {
          "notes": {
            "createdBy": context.user.id, 
            "createdAt": "6/10/10/10",
            "text": input.text
          }
        }
      };

      const options = { returnNewDocument: true }

return collection.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).then(updatedDocument => {
        if(updatedDocument) {
      console.log(`Successfully updated document: ${updatedDocument}.`)
    } else {
      console.log("No document matches the provided query.")
    }
    return {
      _id: updatedDocument._id,
      notes: updatedDocument.notes
    }

  })
  .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to find and update document: ${err}`))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is now returning the correct payload. I'm so glad it was something I had overlooked and not a bigger problem. While reviewing my code logically it made sense to me that the return would come after the promise was complete, but will definitely remember the first return now. 

Also at least now my confusion about the bsonType vs type is cleared up by Drew's response. Now I can move on and create lots of custom resolvers! You guys rock!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bernard – There is an unfortunate bug in the custom resolver form UI at the moment which doesn't allow you to only use bsonType in the input/payload types – we are working on addressing this.  In actually you should be able to use either type/bsonType or a mix of the two as long as they agree with your data.  I think that the payload type definition you want is likely:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "title": "AddNoteToLeadPayload",
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "notes": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "createdAt": {
            "bsonType": "date"
          },
          "createdBy": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work, it might be helpful to give us a sample of the data that you would like returned.

Comment: Hi Drew. Thank you for your response. The type definition you posted above looks correct to me and I think I tried something similar to it. I just retested it and still getting null. 

GraphiQL to test it:

`mutation AddNoteToLead($id: String!, $text: String!) {
  addNoteToLead(input: {id: $id, text: $text}) {
    _id
    }
  }`

Variables:

`{
  "id": "5eca0bd8467c891c2865a779",
  "text": "Test note 1"
}`

Response:

`{
  "data": {
    "addNoteToLead": null
  }
}`

I'll post a sample document in my follow up comment below.

Comment: `_id:ObjectId("5eca0bd8467c891c2865a779")
locked:false
name:"Company name"
map:"null"
website:"http://www.company.com/about-us"
phone:"123-456-7890"
stage:"Lead"
timezone:"E"
badAddressNoWebsite:false
address:"123 State St."
city:"TBD"
state:"TBD"
category:"Metals"
notes:Array
0:Object
createdBy:"5ed35b3898f98ad5a206b752"
createdAt:2020-06-03T02:48:51.145+00:00
text:"Test note 1"
1:Object
createdBy:"5ed35b3898f98ad5a206b752"
createdAt:2020-06-03T02:48:56.309+00:00
text:"Test note 2"`

Comment: Hi Bernard – This seems like it might be a separate function or type validation error which is causing the resolver to return null.  Using the above document I was able to insert and then create a simple custom resolver with the input/payload types above and query it successfully.  Note: I did change dates to strings and changed the function in order to simplify testing.  If you trying calling from a client application you may get a more detailed error log.

Comment: I changed the date to a string and also sending the Custom Mutation from the client application just returned a null value with no error. I also tried a few changes in the function and I'm not sure that the problem is there. I know that returnNewDocument: true is doing what it is supposed to because I console logged the return values. I also thought maybe a problem with findOneandUpdate() so I tried instead updateOne() and return using findOne(). After no luck, I created a new test collection, function, and Mutation resolver with only id and name field and that test return payload is null also